# ¿Cuando se recomiendan usar las excepciones en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, try-catch

estoy aprendiendo el manejo del lenguaje de programación c#, y me surgió la siguiente duda: Yo en un principio validaba los datos numéricos que ingresaba el usuario con un `try catch` (Ya que seria común una excepción por un error del usuario) y de esa forma informar el error y modificar una variable para pedir el dato nuevamente (ver primer código), pero últimamente estuve leyendo que esto puede ser una mala practica ya que consume recursos en una aplicación ya grande, y no es bueno tratar este problema o similares tratándolo en excepciones (yo lo aplicaba porque datos ingresados por el usuario los tomaba como de alto riesgo), en su lugar, hay gente que recomienda el segundo código. 
¿Si lo que hago esta mal, en que casos son en los que se debería aplicar correctamente los bloques `try catch`?

(Primer código)

```
    int num = 0, v;

    do
    {
        v = 1;

        try
        {
            Console.Write(Mensaje);
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            v = 0;

            Console.Write(" (X) Se produjo el siguiente error: {0}", error.Message);
        }


    } while (v == 0);
```

(Segundo código)

```
 int valor;
 string n ;
 bool esNumero;
 do
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Valor Entero");
   n = Console.ReadLine();
   esNumero= int.TryParse(n, out valor);
 }
 while (!esNumero);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien es cierto que se recomienda programar de forma `proactiva` (validando lo que conozcas) a la `reactiva` (dejando el codigo al azar), tampoco es que una exception va a consumir recursos de forma desmedida, si consume mas proceso porque debe generar el objeto `Exception`.

El control de errores deberias agregarlo siempre porque no podras atajar todos los casos que puedan darse, al menos para controlarlo de forma global y loguear en un achivo el problema.

El codigo correcto es el segundo caso, donde controlas la conversion y el flujo de la aplicacion no se escapa con un salto del error

Comment: Gracias Leandro, ¿y en que casos son recomendadas las excepciones? conexiones al servidor y esas cosas?, yo aplicaba la excepción porque vi que estaba el formatexception (formato incorrecto), la overflowexception (desborde) y pensaba que se las penso para eso, pero deben tener otro uso mas indicado

Comment: las excepciones se utilizan principlamente para controlar aquellos casos en el cual no tienes control sobre lo que pasa en el codigo, por ejemplo si creas una conexion a una db debes controlar el posible problema que no puedas conectarte y no hay otra forma de atajarlo que no sea con el control de error. Igual tampoco es algo que debas ser tan riguroso, un poco la experiencia te ira llevando cuando controlar o no los problemas, las exception consumen un poco mas de recursos pero no como para estropear la performance de tu desarrollo